# Hiding a div based on session in PHP

Tags: php, html, session

I have a div that contains a slider when the homepage of the website is opened. What im trying to achieve is that when the website is opened for the first time, the slider should appear. However, if the user goes another page other than the homepage and then returns to the homepage again, the slider should not appear.

Below is the code I am trying to implement:

```
<div class="homeslidermain" style="display:<?php echo empty($_SESSION['first_load']) ? 'block' : 'none'; ?>"> 
<?php putRevSlider("typewriter-effect", "homepage") ?>
</div>
```

Comment: where do you set the first_load var?

Comment: Use a cookie or session. Check if the cookie/session exists or not. If not, show slider and set the cookie/session, if it exists, don't show the slider.

Answer (score 0):

You Could try something like this

```
// start the session 
session_start();

$bShowBanner = true;    

if(isset($_SESSION['BannerShown'])){
    $bShowBanner = false;
}else{
    $_SESSION['BannerShown'] = true;
}
?>

<div class="homeslidermain" style="display:<?php echo ($bShowBanner ? 'block' : 'none'); ?>"> 
    <?php putRevSlider("typewriter-effect", "homepage") ?>
</div>
```

Comment: It would probably be a better idea to not output the slider at all if it's already been shown. Less data to send to the client.

Comment: I agree. Also I feel a better idea would be to use a cookie. To not use inline styles and to stick to some sort of naming convention. However, we do not know if the OP wishes to still have the elements rendered to the page but hidden

Comment: @atoms this does not work as with the above code, the page doesn't load.

Comment: @user38208 are there any error messages? Try putting `<?php` at the start of the script. If you have already set `session_start()`, you do not need to call it again

Comment: The page is just blank. `<?php` has been put yet no change

Comment: @user38208 sorry I had made a mistake with the logic. Working ok now. If you still see no output please check error logs.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve it, best is to check if user visiting page for first time

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['first_load']))
{
   $_SESSION['first_load'] = '1';
}
if(empty($_SESSION['first_load']))
{?>
   <div> 
    Slider block //  this block loads only is first load is empty
   </div>

<?php
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way would be to set a cookie using `setcookie()` and `getcookie()` (http://php.net/manual/de/features.cookies.php).

If you want to use the session then you are setting "first_load" incorrectly. Make sure that on any page call:

```
session_start(); // before you do anything else 

if(!isset($_SESSION['first_load'])) // set it to true on first load
```

... and to false in any other case.

The only reason why this might go wrong is if you are reinitializing your session wrong. Make sure you are still in the same session after switching pages.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to output the `div` as `display:none`. Just output the `div` only when user visits the homepage for the first time. Use the `setcookie()` function to remember that user already visited he homepage, but please note that you should call this function before any output.

```
<?php

if (empty($_COOKIE['homepage_visited'])) {
    // Remember the first visit for one year
    setcookie('homepage_visited', 1, strtotime('+1 year'));

    // Show the slider
    echo '<div class="homeslidermain">';
    putRevSlider("typewriter-effect", "homepage");
    echo '</div>';
}
```